# How do I add the logback env-entry 'logback/context-name' to a Spring Boot restful service

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, logback

I have a Spring Boot restful service which is packaged as a War file and needs to be deployed to Tomcat on our production environment. The production environment already includes other Spring MVC Web apps and I need to follow the same deployment rules by including a Logback file outside of the War file.
The Logback file must follow the naming convention 'logback.appName.xml'. All our other Spring MVC web apps include an 'env-entry' tag in their web.xml file so the webapp knows which Logback file to use e.g.

```
<env-entry>
    <description>JNDI logging context, logback will look for logback-app-name.xml</description>
    <env-entry-name>logback/context-name</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>app-name</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

How do I add the Logback env-entry into my Spring Boot app which does not use a 'web.xml' file?